# resetAllFields in cloned Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have a form with a bunch of input elements and a [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) element. Now, I let the user duplicate the form (via deep `clone`) - each form is submitted independently via AJAX POST.

When the user clones the form, I clear all the input field values using -

```
cloned_form.find('textarea, input').val('');
```

Now, I'd also like to clear the Dropzone element, which I'm trying to do like this -

```
cloned_form.find('form#my-awesome-dropzone').dropzone.resetAllFields();
```

This throws the *"... is not a function"* error. How do I actually reset the Dropzone element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by always maintaining an empty hidden form (with an empty Dropzone), and simply cloning it each time I needed it, while making sure I kept assigning a unique `id` and `name` to each cloned form.